# Swift -Why aren't CALayer images visible inside the Debug View Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, calayer

I have a video that plays inside a `CALayer`. Everything works fine but when I go to the `Debug View Hierarchy`, the `CALayer` that the video plays in, always shows up blank.

Why can't I see the video frame that is visible on the `CALayer` inside the `Debug View Hierarchy`?

[image]

```
class AVPlayerView: UIView {

    var playerLayer: CALayer?

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
    
        playerLayer?.frame = self.bounds
    }
}

lazy var avPlayerView: AVPlayerView = {
    let playerView = AVPlayerView()
    playerView.tag = 2
    return playerView
}()

func setPlayerAndPlayerLayer(url: URL) {

    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    contentView.addSubview(avPlayerView)
    avPlayerView.frame = self.bounds
    playerLayer.frame = avPlayerView.bounds
    avPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
    avPlayerView.playerLayer = playerLayer
    avPlayerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: There might be restriction on whether that layer can be rendered for debugging purposes. Or it might simply be a bug – you can report it to Apple via http://feedbackassistant.apple.com

FWIW, you can view the CALayer tree using the 'Show Layers' option in Xcode's "Editor" menu while using the view debugger. Won't help with your question, but might help you with other layer related debugging challenges.

Comment: thanks for the info. I don’t think it’s a big because I’m all the XCode version since 2018 I haven’t been able to view the CAlayers rendering

Answer (score 1):

It is possible! While using the visual debugger the feature can be toggled at Editor -> Show Layers. This will add layers to the Debug Navigator and selecting them it is possible to inspect their properties.